# Java(Jsoup): How to parse http://host:port

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to parse a web page with Jsoup library. But since its adress is like host and port together (`http://host:port`) (Stackoverflow does not allow to write the exact thing) Jsoup throws an exception and does not parse the page.

Here is the page adress:

And here is the Exception log:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=-1, URL=http://sunucu2.radyolarburada.com:5000/
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:435)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
    at Tester.getSong(Tester.java:136)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:150)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow me to right the link thats why stacktrace is kind of different

Comment: Paste it on different lines, I'll edit for you and make them a link. You can do like: "http colon // www dot example dot org colon 8080".

Comment: I edited it now. Did I edit it right?

Comment: What command did you use to fetch/get the page?

Comment: @acdcjunior

try {
   doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sunucu2.radyolarburada.com:5000/").get();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Can you paste that to your question instead? Also, when you try: `doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sunucu2.radyolarburada.com:5000/").get();` (added `http://`), does it work?

Comment: @acdcjunior no it doesnt work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the `userAgent` in your `Jsoup` request

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://sunucu2.radyolarburada.com:5000/")
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36")
                            .timeout(0).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();
        System.out.println(document.html());
```