# How to connect url with port number in java with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am trying to get HTML in URL(.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("URL").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36").timeout(111110).followRedirects(true).execute().parse();
System.out.println(doc.text());
```

I did userAgent by [Java(Jsoup): How to parse http://host:port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890888/javajsoup-how-to-parse-http-hostport) But It does not work.

How should I connect that URL?

Comment: When you are writing: "But It doesn't work" what do you mean? Did you get an error? If yes what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because this URL under Cloudflare DDoS protection. If you open this URL in a browser you will see that first you got the 503 response code and after that, you will be redirected to the target URL. If you want you can set ignoreHttpErrors to true and you will see that with your code.

```
~ ➭ http http://www.kg348.com:8880/play
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sat, 15 Jul 2017 14:58:52 GMT
Refresh: 8;URL=/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl?pass=sdfsdfsdf.127-dsfsdfd
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=xxxx; expires=Sun, 15-Jul-18 14:58:52 GMT; path=/; domain=.kg348.com; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

And looks like this redirect has been done by javascript, but Jsoup is a parser, it doesn't include a javascript execution engine, so I'm not sure that you are able to get html code of target URL only with Jsoup. In order to execute javascript you will have to use something like selenium webdriver or alternative framework.

Comment: Thank you. I used wget with cookie option. Then parsed html with Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

JSoup allows you to connect to URL and parse the data based on the HTML/Javascript content of the website. Based on your code: Document returns an html document. Before trying the below code make sure you are able to connect to the website *(Note i was able to view the website)*. So modify you code as below:

```
String url="http://www.kg348.com:8880/play"; // your webpage
Document parseURL = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); //will connect and fetch you the HTML content in URL
```

Next parse the elements in the Document using Elements class:

```
Elements ele=parseURL.select("<the html div you want to extract>");
for (Element element : ele) { //using foreach to iterate over every element inside your div or select method
            System.out.println(element.text());
}
```

Hope this will help :)

---

**Edited:**
Removed the timeout() from the Document.

Comment: Thank u! But "Document parseURL = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(111110).get()" this does not work

Comment: Are you sure the website you are trying to parse has allowed your app to access? You may also try to leave the timeout portion of the code?